# WPF data bound ListView/ListVBox won't select if list only has one item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

So this is pretty mystifying. I have a databound `ListBox` (or `ListView`, it happens with both), and if it has more than 2 items in it, selection works - I get a blue highlight bar and the item looks selected. If I only have 1 item, the selection does not work - I do not get a blue highlight bar, but the selection events all fire as normal. Is this a bug in WPF? Or am I just crazy?

This is how I'm setting up my `ListBox`:

```
    <ListView x:Name="plotListBox"
             DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Plots}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPlot, Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"/>
```

Has anyone else run into something like this?
[This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c8a35761-271d-41b4-a55b-2758d06d6412) seems to describe a similar issue, but I can't find anything in the replies that I think would help my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the culprit was `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`. Everything worked fine once I pulled that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" on the ListView`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever had this problem before.  I just used your XAML (but with a static array) in kaxaml and it worked fine.  Then I pasted it to a new WPF project in VS2008 and it was fine.  Here's my code-behind:

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection Plots { get; set; }

```
public Window1()
{
    Plots = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    Plots.Add( "hello");
    //Plots.Add( "world");
}
```

}

just having one item in the ObservableCollection didn't make selection break.